# CASE Clause Is Not Working In SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table "installation_tracking" in my database.

[image: Intallation Tracking Table]

Now what I want is :

1. Total count of mac_id in every case
2. Total count of distinct mac_id every case
3. Total count of mac_id if uninstalled_date is not '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
4. Total count of distinct mac_id if uninstalled_date is not '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

This whole should be group by rs_id

I tried this out by the following query but it did not work.

```
SELECT count(it.mac_id) AS total_installations, count(distinct it.mac_id) AS unique_installations,
CASE  
  WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN count(it.mac_id)
END as total_uninstallations,
CASE  
  WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN count(distinct it.mac_id)
END as total_uninstallations

FROM installation_tracking it GROUP BY it.rs_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(it.mac_id) AS total_installations, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT it.mac_id) AS unique_installations,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
             THEN it.mac_id 
             ELSE NULL
             END) as total_uninstallations,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
                      THEN it.mac_id 
                      ELSE NULL
                      END) as unique_uninstallations
FROM installation_tracking it 
GROUP BY it.rs_id
```

By returning `NULL` when the value does not match the criterion, you prevent the irrelevant values from being counted.

As funkwurm stated, the `ELSE NULL` parts are optional, as the `CASE` clause will return `NULL` by default anyway. I personally find them more readable though.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is the way to go. I'm wondering whether you even need the `ELSE NULL` part. I believe `CASE` returns `NULL` when no `WHEN` condition is met and there's no `ELSE` defined?

Comment: @funkwurm You're right. I got used to put the ELSE clause everywhere, I personnaly find this more explicit.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's more readible for your (future) colleagues etc. with the `ELSE NULL` explicitly there.

Answer (score 0):

The outcome of `COUNT()` is not influenced by `CASE WHEN`, you'd have to but that in the `WHERE` but that influences all your results. There's a little trick to use if you wanna conditionally count without a `WHERE`. You actually do a `SUM()` and the input for that will be 1 or 0 depending on the outcome of the condition:

```
SELECT count(it.mac_id) AS total_installations, count(distinct it.mac_id) AS unique_installations,
SUM(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_uninstallations,
SUM(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_uninstallations

FROM installation_tracking it GROUP BY it.rs_id
```

Of course like this the last one doesn't do `DISTINCT`. I don't have a solution for that of the top of my head. Might have to be its own query, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(it.mac_id) AS total_installations
, count(distinct it.mac_id) AS unique_installations
, SUM(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_uninstallations
, SUM(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_uninstallations

FROM installation_tracking it GROUP BY it.rs_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the case/sum unside out:

```
SELECT count(it.mac_id) AS total_installations,
       count(distinct it.mac_id) AS unique_installations,
       SUM(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN 1 else 0 end) as total_uninstallations1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN 1 else 0 end) as total_uninstallations2
FROM installation_tracking it
GROUP BY it.rs_id
```

BTW, same column alias can't be re-used...

Answer (score -1):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT count(it.mac_id) AS total_installations, count(distinct it.mac_id) AS unique_installations,
  CASE  
  WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN count(it.mac_id)
  WHEN it.uninstalled_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN count(distinct it.mac_id) 
  END as total_uninstallations
FROM installation_tracking it GROUP BY it.rs_id
```